# shared memory segment can't be removed after call shmdt()

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

i called shmdt() successfully, but shared memory segment can't be removed..

this is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    key_t key = ftok(".", 'T');
    if (key == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "get key failed, error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int) * 10, IPC_CREAT);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "get shmid failed, error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    void* shmaddr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (shmaddr == (void*)-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "get shmaddr failed, error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (shmdt(shmaddr) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "detach failed, error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

after that, i execute `ipcs -m`

```
# ipcs -m

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 1179648    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1212417    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1245186    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1277955    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1310724    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1343493    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1376262    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1409031    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1441800    root       0          4          0                       
0x00000000 1474569    root       0          4          0                       
0x54010004 1671178    root       0          40         0                       
0x00000000 1540107    root       0          4          0
```

Comment: You need to use `shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);` to remove the shared memory segment.

Comment: when the shmid_ds::shm_nattch == 0, the shared memory segment will be removed automatically????@Gaurav Pathak

Comment: No, it just indicates whether your shared memory is attached with any process or not. If shmid_ds->shm_nattach == 0 then it means it can be attached to another process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> shmdt() detaches the shared memory segment located at the address
>   specified by shmaddr from the address space of the calling process.
>   The to-be-detached segment must be currently attached with shmaddr
>   equal to the value returned by the attaching shmat() call.

shmdt only **detaches** the calling process from attached memory. It will **not** **remove** the shared memory created by the process.
For more information please read the man page of the respective system calls.